# How to merge rows using start and finish timestamps of a consecutive id count in R, but per-group basis?

Tags: r, time, data-manipulation

### The data:

```
      id station start               stop               
   <int>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1     1       1 1899-12-31 00:05:04 1899-12-31 00:13:36
 2     2       1 1899-12-31 00:14:04 1899-12-31 00:21:32
 3     3       1 1899-12-31 00:21:32 1899-12-31 00:26:56
 4     4       1 1899-12-31 00:26:57 1899-12-31 00:27:10
 5     1       1 1899-12-31 00:38:32 1899-12-31 00:38:38
 6     3       1 1899-12-31 00:43:23 1899-12-31 00:43:47
 7     5       1 1899-12-31 00:53:00 1899-12-31 00:53:15
 8     6       1 1899-12-31 00:53:29 1899-12-31 00:55:49
 9     6       1 1899-12-31 00:56:15 1899-12-31 00:56:42
10     7       1 1899-12-31 01:14:30 1899-12-31 01:28:09
11     3       1 1899-12-31 01:28:09 1899-12-31 01:31:17
12     3       2 1899-12-31 01:34:22 1899-12-31 01:35:11
13     7       3 1899-12-31 01:36:44 1899-12-31 01:39:54
14     8       3 1899-12-31 01:41:49 1899-12-31 01:44:45
15     9       2 1899-12-31 01:44:47 1899-12-31 01:52:07
```

### The need:

I need to merge the times of repeated id's so that they count as just one. For example, id #6 has two consecutive actions, each with a start and stop times (lines 8 and 9). The desired output would be that instead of this:

```
11     3       1 1899-12-31 01:28:09 1899-12-31 01:31:17
12     3       2 1899-12-31 01:34:22 1899-12-31 01:35:11
```

Something like this would be shown

```
11     3       1 1899-12-31 01:28:09 1899-12-31 01:35:11
```

So, both events as a single event with the first start timestamp, and the stop of the second one.

### The caveat

This solution should merge times only if they belong to the same `station`, so for example in the sample data id #3 in line 11 would not be merged with line 12, since they belong to different stations.

A solution using tools from tidyverse is preferred but not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try the following. Assign a unique second id `id2` that will be the same for repeat, consecutive `id`'s. Then, after grouping by the new `id2`, `summarise` and take the `first` `start` and the `last` `stop` dates/times.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(id2 = rleid(id)) %>%
  group_by(id2) %>%
  summarise(id = first(id), start = first(start), stop = last(stop)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(id, start, stop)
```

**Output**

```
      id start               stop               
   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1     1 1899-12-31 00:05:04 1899-12-31 00:13:36
 2     2 1899-12-31 00:14:04 1899-12-31 00:21:32
 3     3 1899-12-31 00:21:32 1899-12-31 00:26:56
 4     4 1899-12-31 00:26:57 1899-12-31 00:27:10
 5     1 1899-12-31 00:38:32 1899-12-31 00:38:38
 6     3 1899-12-31 00:43:23 1899-12-31 00:43:47
 7     5 1899-12-31 00:53:00 1899-12-31 00:53:15
 8     6 1899-12-31 00:53:29 1899-12-31 00:56:42
 9     7 1899-12-31 01:14:30 1899-12-31 01:28:09
10     3 1899-12-31 01:28:09 1899-12-31 01:35:11
11     7 1899-12-31 01:36:44 1899-12-31 01:39:54
12     8 1899-12-31 01:41:49 1899-12-31 01:44:45
13     9 1899-12-31 01:44:47 1899-12-31 01:52:07
```

---

For the caveat with different stations for a given `id` you can add `station` to `rleid`, such that you will get a unique `id2` for each combination of `id` and `station` combined.

In addition, you can use `unique` as alternative to `first` in `summarise` to keep the column values you need (just an option).

```
df %>%
  mutate(id2 = rleid(id, station)) %>%
  group_by(id2) %>%
  summarise(id = unique(id), station = unique(station), start = first(start), stop = last(stop)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(id, station, start, stop)
```

**Output**

```
      id station start               stop               
   <int>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1     1       1 1899-12-31 00:05:04 1899-12-31 00:13:36
 2     2       1 1899-12-31 00:14:04 1899-12-31 00:21:32
 3     3       1 1899-12-31 00:21:32 1899-12-31 00:26:56
 4     4       1 1899-12-31 00:26:57 1899-12-31 00:27:10
 5     1       1 1899-12-31 00:38:32 1899-12-31 00:38:38
 6     3       1 1899-12-31 00:43:23 1899-12-31 00:43:47
 7     5       1 1899-12-31 00:53:00 1899-12-31 00:53:15
 8     6       1 1899-12-31 00:53:29 1899-12-31 00:56:42
 9     7       1 1899-12-31 01:14:30 1899-12-31 01:28:09
10     3       1 1899-12-31 01:28:09 1899-12-31 01:31:17
11     3       2 1899-12-31 01:34:22 1899-12-31 01:35:11
12     7       3 1899-12-31 01:36:44 1899-12-31 01:39:54
13     8       3 1899-12-31 01:41:49 1899-12-31 01:44:45
14     9       2 1899-12-31 01:44:47 1899-12-31 01:52:07
```

Comment: thanks! going to try this now. I took a method from a similar issue that creates a "flag" column with a value of 1 for repeated events, I might adapt this into that.

Comment: Pretty close! I just needed to add the original id column, because id2 does not make any sense. 

This did the trick:
```mutate(id2 = rleid(id)) %>%

  group_by(id2) %>%

  summarise(id = id, start = first(start), stop = last(stop)) %>%

  ungroup() %>%

  select(id, start, stop) %>%

  distinct(id, start, stop)```

Comment: Happy to edit the answer. You can probably just include `id = first(id)`...

Comment: See edited answer - does this work? If think you can just include the `first` id, since by `id2` all `id` should be the same. Then you can get by without `distinct`...

Comment: Ben, what if I had the same data but with an extra column named ```station```. How would I loop this over just one station (```1```) and then move to the next station and apply this same method?

Comment: Could you edit your question with the extra column in an example? Then I can revise the code to match. Include both starting data and desired output if you can.

Comment: Done, check new data and title "the caveat"

Comment: Can you try `mutate(id2 = rleid(id, station))` instead of what we have above? That would make a unique `id2` for each `id`/`station` combination, so same `id` with different `station` would not get merged. If this works, will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Had to add ``` station = first(station)``` in ```summarize``` and ```station``` in ```select()``` as well. It was not clear in the newly edited question. I will add that now. 
Will need to look up for that ```rleid()``` function, definitely.

Comment: Yes sounds right to me